# How to insert test data of Territory2 and UserTerritory2Association in test class?

Tags: unit-testing, salesforce, apex, apex-code

I have a class which is using `Territory2` and `UserTerritory2Association` objects. So I need to cover these lines.
Can you please tell me how to insert test data of `Territory2` and `UserTerritory2Association` kind?

Thanks,
Raj.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to understand required fields on different objects related to Territory

1. UserTerritory2Association required fields are Territory2Id and UserId
2. Territory2 Object required fields :- AccountAccessLevel, CaseAccessLevel, DeveloperName, Name, OpportunityAccessLevel, Territory2ModelId, Territory2TypeId
3. Territory2Model required Fields:- DeveloperName, Name
4. Territory2Type required Fields :- DeveloperName,MasterLabel, Priority

So below are the steps

1. Create Territory2Type record with all required fields
2. Create Territory2Model record with all required fields
3. Create Territory2 record with all required fields, and having the reference for Territory2Type and Territory2Model  from step 1 and 2
4. Create a User record
5. Create a UserTerritory2Association record with userId from step 4 and Territory2Id from step 3, remember the combination of userId and Territory2Id must be unique for every record otherwise you will get Duplicate record exception